# Каст абстрактного класса к конкретной реализации

Tags: java, ооп

Есть метод, возвращающий экземпляр абстрактного класса и перегруженные методы, которые принимают всех существующих наследников.

```
AbstractClass getSuccessor() {
    return ...;
}

void work(SonOfAbstract child);

void work(DaughterOfAbstract child);

void work(GrandchildOfAbstract child);
```

Метод `getSuccessor()` гарантировано возвращает наследника `AbstractClass` и метод `work` умеет работать со всеми наследниками.

Но вот вызов `work(getSuccessor());` ожидаемо не проходит , так как метод `work(AbstractClass child)` не определен. Для родителя и сферического наследника в вакууме работы нет.

Как можно передать наследника в метод, а JRE пускай само разбирается, какой метод вызывать?

Comment: может быть `work` вынести в  сам `*OfAbstract` класс?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно метод `work` освободить от параметров если добавить его как абстрактный метод в `AbstractClass`. И затем имплементировать его для конкретного класса наследника. Это даёт возможность использовать абстрактный класс или интерфейс для хранения конкретной имплементации классов наследников и не привязывается к конкретному типу. Далее в зависимости от того какой конкретный тип будет использоваться вместо интерфейса в рантайме определится с помощью полиморфизма.

Этот метод не только освободит от привязки к типам, а также избавит от ненужных кастов. Проверка на тип с помощью `instanceof` а также вдобавок `if else if` как известно приводят к замедлению работы программы.

Answer (score 2):

Какая-то гниль в датском королевстве.

```
AbstractClass item = getSuccessor();

if (item instanceof GrandchildOfAbstract)
  work((GrandchildOfAbstract)item);
else if (item instanceof SonOfAbstract)
  work((SonOfAbstract)item);
else if (item instanceof DaughterOfAbstract)
  work((DaughterOfAbstract)item);
```