# Что означает действие в скобках?

Tags: java

Что означает действие в скобках конкретно в моей ситуации?

```
GamePerson oneRestore = (GamePerson) myPers.readObject();
```

именно действие в скобках `(GamePerson)`

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;


    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            GamePerson one = new GamePerson(50 ,"Эльф",new String[] {"лук", "копье", "меч"});
            GamePerson two = new GamePerson(200 ,"Тролль",new String[] {"дубина", "палеса", "меч"});
            GamePerson three = new GamePerson(100 ,"Маг",new String[] {"посох", "книга заклинаний", "нож"});

            FileOutputStream personsGame = new FileOutputStream("personsGame.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream pG = new ObjectOutputStream(personsGame);

            pG.writeObject(one);
            pG.writeObject(two);
            pG.writeObject(three);

            one = null;
            two = null;
            three = null;

            try (ObjectInputStream myPers = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("personsGame.ser"))) {
                GamePerson oneRestore = (GamePerson) myPers.readObject();
                GamePerson twoRestore = (GamePerson) myPers.readObject();
                GamePerson threeRestore =(GamePerson)myPers.readObject();

                System.out.println("Ваш персонаж " + oneRestore.getType());
                System.out.println("Ваш персонаж " + twoRestore.getType());
                System.out.println("Ваш персонаж " + threeRestore.getType());
            }








        }
    }

       import java.io.Serializable;

public class GamePerson implements Serializable {
    int power;
    String type;
    String[] weapons;

    public GamePerson(int p, String t, String[] w) {
        power = p;
        type = t;
        weapons = w;
    }

    public String getType() {

        return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: InputStream читает из файла и на "выходе" получается объект неизвестного типа (общий для всех объектов тип Object). В скобках мы указываем, что полученный объект именно типа GamePerson (делаем приведение к типу), чтобы можно было использовать свойства и методы именно объектов этого типа

Comment: Вот что нужно делать, чтобы подобного не происходило https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/875517/204920

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GamePerson oneRestore = (GamePerson) myPers.readObject();
```

`(GamePerson)` означает преобразование типа.

`myPers.readObject()` возвращает (вероятно) результат типа `Object` (вернее, ссылку на `Object`), и без этого преобразования компилятор выдаст ошибку. Этим преобразованием (кастом - "cast") программист говорит компилятору, что он знает, что делает, что он уверен в том, что за ссылкой на `Object` скрывается `GamePerson`. Если же там не `GamePerson` (или наследник/реализация этого типа), а что-то другое, то произойдет ошибка выполнения (run-time error) - будет выброшено исключение.

Comment: Ок , спасибо , а еще вопрос , бросок вверх по классам-наследникам так же вроде тоже обозначается , или я ошибаюсь ??

Comment: @МаксимШевченков "бросок вверх по классу" - что это значит?

Comment: Так стоп что то меня понесло не туда)) в любом случае спасибо за ответ

Comment: @МаксимШевченков Что это за хамское "в любом случае"? Вас что, не устраивает содержание ответа?

Comment: Нет , все в порядке , я не имел ввиду ничего плохого , ответ был дан более чем понятный , немного недопоняли друг друга , извиняюсь если что не так

Comment: @МаксимШевченков Тогда вопрос вопрос исчерпан, спасибо. Знак "галочка" - слева.